# while searching a very large text file as most commonly the text editors offer, how does the memory alloted?

Tags: memory, memory-management

while searching a very large text file as most commonly the text editors offer, how does the memory alloted so that while searching the "out of space" error does not occur. Is there any special algorithm for this?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding your question, you're asking:
   When mapping an arbitrarily large file into memory, how does the process map it all into memory?

This is actually a very fascinating, and very deep, question.
Naturally, that means the answer is going to be similarly lengthy and intricate. So without further ado.

Firstly, we need to explore how much memory our theoretical text editor can have at maximum. The first limit on this will be how much a modern computer can physically address (while oversimplifying and ignoring the existence of the page file, letting it address more memory than it has), which is limited by the address bus. On modern 64-bit systems, only the lower 48 bits of the address bus are exposed. This means that at most the CPU can physically address 256 terabytes of ram.

Significantly overkill, compared to the common 16 gigabyte system.

Now, however, we have another limit imposed on us; virtual memory and the size of the page file. On a modern operating system processes have pages of virtual memory which the OS allocates to each one (this is why every process can place it's code at the same address in memory without colliding and very bad things happening.). There is a maximum amount of pages the OS can give to each process, which varies by platform and system settings. Usually, though, it is *much* less than even the limited amount of physical memory we typically see. However is it still a similarly absurd amount (usually so much that an average program only uses ~2% of the total memory afforded)

(A side note here is that there is a differentiation between pages the process has allocated and is using, versus ones it has allocated but not touched. When you allocate a page it is initially a clone of the so called 'zero page', because all pages are initialized to zero. Once you start writing to a page, the OS then allocates a page for that process.)

So, that's now our next limit on the theoretical text editor.

Second we need to understand how these processes map files into memory.

Using Linux as an example, when you use the `mmap` function to load the file, you can specify a window of how much of the file you want to map. So a program may only map a portion of the file at a time as it works.

With the prior statement about how much memory is afforded, though, it is obvious this isn't the issue.

Thirdly, we arrive to both the bottleneck.and the solution: paging.

A process may very well map a multi-gigabyte file into memory, however only a small subset of that file will reside in ram at a time. The OS will "page out" sections which are not being accessed to the page file on disk. (Remember I mentioned this behavior earlier?) So, this is really the answer to your question. Our little text editing program really doesn't need to concern itself with such problems. It may map an arbitrarily large window (up to some absurd limit. For example on 32 bit operating systems it could only address 4 gigabytes of memory at a time, modern 64 bit systems are not similarly bounded.) and let the OS manage moving the data it cares about in and out of ram as needed.

I hope this helps! :)